# Obtaining access_token from the uid

Tags: facebook, access-token

So i made an app, I setup the auth and permissions and i have users with offline access granted. But i did NOT save the access_token in the database.

Is there a way to obtain the **access_token** from the **uid** so i can make some API calls (rsvp to event)?

Answer (score 0):

Once the user comes back into your app via the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) flow, you'll get an updated token. You can't get an access token without the user coming back though.